# SoapClient module shipping Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am creating a new module to shipping methods in Magento 2.

I create a model where appends the methods but I need run a web service soap client. I add the row: `$soapClient = new Zend\Soap\Client(NULL,'http://www.example.com/oi/x/st/?wsdl');` but when run the code show an error but not have message:

[image]

If I not put the line it works correctly. I know this is the error.

Error in console:

[image]

The error I think is because the line `$soapClient = new Zend\Soap\Client(NULL,'http://www.example.com/oi/x/st/?wsdl');` not work and the code not continue and not append methods. If I commment this line not show errors the console

Use this:

```
try {
     $soapClient = new Zend\Soap\Client(NULL,'http://www.example.com/oi/x/st/?wsdl');
} catch (Exception $e) {
     $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/module1.log');
     $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
     $logger->addWriter($writer);
     $logger->info($e->getMessage());
}
```

In file module1.log not show anything.

Comment: Copy error from browser console.

Comment: wrap in in a try-catch

Comment: Marius I edit the post. I use try catch but not show execptions

Comment: Could you check console output using firebug+firefox?

Comment: I discover first error. I not put "\" in Zend\Soap\Client. But I have an error calling the method but show the error Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-588f5f7fef1df. This error in log put unknown reason